# update curl on centos

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

There is curl v7.19.7 on my cnetos. Since I want to develop c++ program to send email, I got the curl v7.50.3 source code and install it(configure, make, make install). Although my c++ program build successfully, but when I try to execute it, there are errors:

```
* Protocol smtp not supported or disabled in libcurl
* Unsupported protocol
curl_easy_perform() failed: Unsupported protocol
```

When I proceed command: curl --version, it shows:

```
curl 7.50.3 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.13.6.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
```

It seems libcurl still refer to the older version!

Although I try to

```
1. rpm -q curl
2. rpm -e --nodeps curl-7.19.7-35.el6.x86_64
```

but it comes out no difference. I also add "/usr/local/lib" in /etc/ld.so.conf, still not working!

How can I do to remove old version curl library(v7.19.7) clearly, let my c++ program refer to the new version curl(v7.50.3)?

Comment: did you run `ldconfig` after editing `/etc/ld.so.conf` ?

Comment: Your run-time linker finds your older libcurl (that's still installed) earlier in the path.

Comment: Thanks a lot for @ymonad's help, it turns out I didn't run ldconfig" to update the link! After run "ldconfig" my problem solved! BTW, just being curious, is "rpm -e --nodeps curl-7.19.7-35.el6.x86_64" necessary? Or just run "ldconfig" can make link updated?

Comment: @jones321 I don't think removing the curl package itself using `rpm -e --nodeps ` command is necessary in this case.  `ldconfig` is a command that parses `/etc/ld.so.conf` and update `/etc/ld.so.cache` which is used by dynamic loader. In your case just updating `/etc/ld.so.conf` was not enough since dynamic loader uses this `/etc/ld.so.cache` file, and wont read `/etc/ld.so.conf` each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using "ldd" on your executable to check what version of curl it is using.

Make sure the libcurl path matches "/usr/local/lib" or whereever you installed the curl you compiled

```
[user@computer bin]$ ldd myExecutable | grep curl
libcurl.so.4 => /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4 (0x00...)
```

Comment: SMTP is enabled by default.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! For my case, its "ldconfig" needed to update link... But I  learn the "ldd" command usage from yout answer~ Thanks!

Comment: Nicolas: your answer will be much better if you remove the entire `--enable-smtp` suggestion since it was wrong.

Comment: There i fixed it :), Thanks for the advice

Comment: Jones321, if you found the solution, you can add an answer to your own question with the solution. So that people can clearly see the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following commands;

```
rpm -Uvh http://www.city-fan.org/ftp/contrib/yum-repo/city-fan.org-release-2-1.rhel6.noarch.rpm
yum --enablerepo=city-fan.org update curl
```

Enter this command to see the version;

```
curl -V
```

Comment: Repo is not available any more `Retrieving http://www.city-fan.org/ftp/contrib/yum-repo/city-fan.org-release-2-1.rhel6.noarch.rpm
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
error: skipping http://www.city-fan.org/ftp/contrib/yum-repo/city-fan.org-release-2-1.rhel6.noarch.rpm - transfer failed`

Comment: Probably they have closed the repo.